# using map with None type functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

exists in python an equivalent to Haskell's mapM_ function?

example ("print()" is here only a placeholder for every function with Signature: a -> None):

```
#pseudo code!!!
map (lambda x: print(x), [1,2,3])
```

like in Haskell:

```
mapM_ :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m ()
> mapM_ print [1,2]
> 1
> 2
```

Comment: Sidenote: `lambda x: func(x)` is redundant. Just use `func`. This is called eta-reduction.

Comment: Related: [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?](/q/5753597/4518341)

Comment: What are you asking? `map` works with *any callable*, the "signature" (which isn't really a thing in python) is irrelevant

Answer (score 2):

`map` just creates a lazy iterator. You would have to consume such an iterator (e.g. by calling `list` on it) in order to harvest the side-effects. Since that wastes memory (as do other collection constructors), the recommended [consume recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) uses a zero size `collections.deque`:

```
from collections import deque

def consume(iterator):
    deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
```

Now, you can consume an iterator with a small memory footprint:

```
lazy = map(print, [1,2,3])  # using lambda here defeats the purpose of functions
consume(lazy)
```

But TMK this provides little advantage over a simple loop:

```
for x in [1, 2, 3]:
    print(x)
```

Comment: Can also do `print(*iterable, sep="\n")` :D

Comment: +1, FWIW OP was using `print()` as a stand-in for any function which returns `None` so your consume recipe is the actual answer OP needs.

Comment: What's "TMK"? "to my knowledge"?

Comment: @wjandrea I thought so :D no? I'm not the greatest expert in the acronyms the kids use these days.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I've never heard it before. I'd use "AFAIK" ("as far as I know") instead, though personally, I try to avoid using acronyms in answers for maximum clarity, especially for non-native speakers.